# What is the divisor notation used (for example) in Hpricot?

Tags: ruby, hpricot

In the Hpricot docs (at https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot) there is a doc.search() method. The docs then go on to say "A shortcut is to use the divisor":

```
(doc/"p.posted")
```

It works, that's for sure, but I'm wondering, what notation is this? I have never come across it before.

Comment: What do you mean by "what notation"? It's just a method shortcut. Many of Ruby's "operators" are actually method calls. For example `4 / 2` is equivalent to `4.send(:'/', 2)`

Comment: @noodl, "For example 4 / 2 is equivalent to 4.send(:'/', 2)". Mostly wrong. The OP wants to know what `/` means in Hpricot, which is an alias to `search`.

Comment: @the Tin Man: in what universe does "what notation is this" mean "what does this do?" And how is my example wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` is just a regular method, which can be called in an infix style:

```
>> 8 / 2 #=> 4
>> 8./ 2 #=> 4
```

Just define one for your own classes:

```
>> class Myclass
..   def /(n)
..     "Yeah" * n
..     end
..   end #=> nil
>> Myclass.new / 5 #=> "YeahYeahYeahYeahYeah"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Hpricot.

Comment: It was meant as answer to "what notation is this", explaining that it is now special notation, just a regular method. If you look at the question title, it says "What is the divisor notation used (for example) in Hpricot?" Since there is no such thing as a "divisor notation", just a `/` method, that was what I answered.

Answer (score 4):

Hpricot (and Nokogiri, because it support's Hpricot's shortcuts) supports two shortcut methods for "search", (`/`) and "at" (`%`).

`Search` means "find all occurrences of this pattern" and `at` means find the first occurrence. `Search` returns a list of nodes, while `at` returns a single node, which you have to keep in mind when you want to access the contents of the node.

Generally, `at` is good for tags or IDs you know to be unique and will not want to iterate over. `Search` is for things like walking over all rows in a table, or every `<p>` tag in a document. You can also chain from an `%`, which is useful for finding a particular node, then descending into it.

```
require 'hpricot'

html = '
<html>
  <head><title>blah</title>
  <body>
    <div id="foo">
      <p>paragraph1</p>
      <p>paragraph2</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
'
doc = Hpricot(html)

doc.at('title').inner_text  # => "blah"
(doc / 'p').last.inner_text # => "paragraph2"
(doc % 'p').inner_text # => "paragraph1"
(doc % '#foo').search('p').size # => 2
```

Personally, I recommend [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) over Hpricot. It supports all the short-cuts but is more full-featured, and very well supported.

And, the shortcuts `/` and `%` are not parts of any standard that I've seen; They're local to Hpricot, and were inherited by Nokogiri for convenience. I don't remember seeing them in Perl or Python parsers.

Answer (score 3):

The notation is probably meant to evoke [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) using an overloaded `/` operator:

> / selects the document root (which is always the parent of the document element)

The operator needs two arguments and the LHS supplies the overloading context so you have to say

```
doc/"p.posted"
```

rather than just

```
/"p.posted"
```

Comment: Hpricot supports XPath and CSS accessors. `/` is a short-cut for `search` which means "find all nodes matching that search target."

Comment: That's what I said, the notation evokes (i.e. brings to mind) the XPath notation for "start at the root".